# Unexpected result: query to show tblA records if tblA.ID doesn't match tblB.ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made a query to show tblA records if tblA.ID doesn't match tblB.ID. The query works fine only if there is at least one record in tblB, but if tblB has no records then the query of tblA will return empty, though tblA should return all its records. Below is the code with the unexpected result:

```
SELECT tblA.id
FROM tblA INNER JOIN tblB ON tblA.id = tblB.id;
```

The Unexpected result also occurs in this format:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblA , tblB 
WHERE tblA .id Not Like tblB .id;
```

Example of the desired an undesired results:

[image]

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN`, not an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: [Look at this and bookmark it](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: An error? As in an error message, or as in wrong/unexpected result?

Comment: Thanks jarlh, I edited the question to be clearer. And it's an unexpected result.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text!

Comment: Siual, thanks. But a LEFT JOIN shows all records, doesn't consider the NOT LIKE condition. Bellow the code:

SELECT tblA.id
FROM tblA
LEFT JOIN tblB ON tblA.id Not Like tblB.id
GROUP BY tblA.id

Comment: @CEIEC Please show sample data and a desired result - that's a different query from what you have in your question.  Do you want to `JOIN` on the `ID`s matching or not matching?  I've no idea what you're trying to do...

Comment: No pictures please, we want well formatted text!

Comment: @Siyual, thanks for the quick answer. I posted an image with the disired and undesired results.

Comment: Note: if ID is null, `NOT LIKE` will return null and results will not be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case Left join should be used.
Try it.

```
select tbl1.Id
from tbl1 
left join tbl2 on tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id
where tbl2.Id is null
```

Comment: Thanks @user7369792, your code worked! Many thanks to everyone who made suck fast support, this is really an awesome community!

Comment: http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/ will help in better understanding of Joins.

Comment: Your's welcome @CEIEC . If you find it an appropriate answer you can mark it as an answer, this will  surely be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

select * from tblA 
where id in 
(
select id from tblA
except 
select id from tblB
)

Comment: Thanks  Venkat, but occurs a syntax error 'id in ( select id from tblA except select id from tblB )'

Comment: CEIEC,which database are you using?